# Error: No tests found. You may need to escape symbols like "$" or "*" and quote the arguments

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

Error: No tests found.
Make sure that arguments are regular expressions matching test files.
You may need to escape symbols like "$" or "*" and quote the arguments.

I am Getting this error whenever I run my code.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it.

I am not able to run my code.

Comment: You might want to post a snippet of the code that's failing and maybe provide some more information about your environment. In general, characters within a RegEx are escaped with a \, for example `\*`

Comment: As above, you need to add / to the start and end of your regex in playwright to escape. Use something like regex101.com to test them

Comment: Please share minimal code and run command. It's hard to help otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find missing curly braces {} or unclosed comments /*...*/ or misplaced code in your code.